# Laravel LoginController

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, controller

I have a LoginController in Laravel, but I think it could use some improving, can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? It just seems overall a bit messy, but I can't think of a logical way to improve it.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Ec9\Frontend\Guest;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Database\Ec9\Website\LoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Redirect;
use Auth;
use App\Database\Ec9\Other\PlatformSetting;
use App\Database\Ec9\Other\User;
use Jenssegers\Agent\Agent;
use Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function getLoginView() {
        return view('frontend.guest.login');
    }

    public function onLoginPost(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'login_email'     => 'required|email|exists:users,mail',
            'login_password'  => 'required'
        ]);

        Session::put('last_message_for', 'login');

        if ( $validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->messages());
        }
        else {
            if (!Auth::attempt(['mail' => $request->input('login_email'), 'password' => $request->input('login_password')])) {
                $this->addNewWebsiteLogin($request, User::where('mail', $request->input('login_email'))->pluck('id')->first(), "0");
                return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Opps, you entered an incorrect login.')->withColor('warning');
            }
            else {
                $user = Auth::user();
                $rpInfo = $user->roleplayInformation;

                $this->addNewWebsiteLogin($request, $user->id, "1");

                $country = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $request->ip()))->country_name;

                if ($user->ip_last != $request->ip() && strlen(Auth::user()->ip_last) > 0) {
                    if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_ip == '1') {
                        $user->lockAccount("Detected a login from a different IP address.");
                    }
                    else if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_country == '1' && strlen(Auth::user()->last_country) > 0 && Auth::user()->last_country != $country) {
                        $user->lockAccount("Detected a login from a different country.");
                    }

                    if ($user->is_locked == '0') {
                        if ($user->website_pin_selection == 'different_ip') {
                            $user->pin_lock = '1';
                        }
                        else if ($user->website_pin_selection == 'different_country' && strlen(Auth::user()->last_country) > 0 && Auth::user()->last_country != $country) {
                            $user->pin_lock = '1';
                        }
                    }
                }

                if ($user->is_locked == '0' && $user->pin_lock == '0' && $user->website_pin_selection == 'every_login') {
                    $user->pin_lock = '1';
                }

                $user->ip_last = $request->ip();
                $user->last_country = $country;
                $user->save();

                return redirect()->route('frontend.user.home');
            }
        }
    }

        private function addNewWebsiteLogin(Request $request, $userId, $status) {
            $agent = new Agent();
            $loginRequest = new LoginRequest;
            $loginRequest->user_id = $userId;
            $loginRequest->password_tried = ($status == '0' ? $request->input('login_password') : '');
            $loginRequest->request_ip = $request->ip();
            $loginRequest->request_device = $agent->isDesktop() ? 'Desktop' : ($agent->isMobile() ? 'Mobile' : 'Tablet');
            $loginRequest->request_system = $agent->platform() . ' ' . $agent->version($agent->platform());
            $loginRequest->request_browser = $agent->browser();
            $loginRequest->request_successful = $status;
            $loginRequest->save();
        }
}
```

Comment: "_can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?_" does that imply there are errors/bugs, or is it just an opinionated *wrong*?

Answer (score 2):

Just refactored the one function.
It is hard to tell what your intentions are in some places.

Comments are inline, with reasons as to why I changed things

```
    public function onLoginPost(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'login_email'     => 'required|email|exists:users,mail',
            'login_password'  => 'required'
        ]);

        Session::put('last_message_for', 'login');

        if ( $validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator->messages());
        }

        // the prior statement returns, no need for an else here
        // else {
        if (!Auth::attempt(['mail' => $request->input('login_email'), 'password' => $request->input('login_password')])) {
            $this->addNewWebsiteLogin($request, User::where('mail', $request->input('login_email'))->pluck('id')->first(), "0");
            return Redirect::back()->withMessage('Opps, you entered an incorrect login.')->withColor('warning');
        }

        // the prior statement returns, no need for an else here
        // else {

        // we assign user to a variable, but still use Auth::user() thru the following code?
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rpInfo = $user->roleplayInformation;

        $this->addNewWebsiteLogin($request, $user->id, "1");

        // what no error checking, what if this request fails?
        // maybe this should be abstracted in a separate function, for example, $this->getCountryNameByIp($request->ip());
        $country = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $request->ip()))->country_name;

        // this is not essential, i just find it more readable this way
        // if ($user->ip_last != $request->ip() && strlen(Auth::user()->ip_last) > 0) {
        $is_different_ip = (!empty(Auth::user()->ip_last) && $user->ip_last != $request->ip());

        // not sure why you are checking for string versions of a what is essentially a boolean
        // if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_ip == '1') {
        if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_ip && $is_different_ip) {
            $user->lockAccount("Detected a login from a different IP address.");
        }

        // i have split these conditions up, just for the sake of readability
        // if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_country == '1' && strlen(Auth::user()->last_country) > 0 && Auth::user()->last_country != $country) {
        $is_different_country = (!empty(Auth::user()->last_country) && Auth::user()->last_country != $country);
        if ($rpInfo->lock_account_on_different_country && $is_different_country) {
            $user->lockAccount("Detected a login from a different country.");
        }

        // personal preference again, if you are using booleans, leave the == bit out
        // if ($user->is_locked == '0') {
        if (!$user->is_locked) {

            // to me it seems like you don't need to test for a different country again, but hard to tell without seeing the user class
    //      if ($user->website_pin_selection == 'different_ip') {
    //          $user->pin_lock = '1';
    //      }
    //      else if ($user->website_pin_selection == 'different_country' && strlen(Auth::user()->last_country) > 0 && Auth::user()->last_country != $country) {
    //          $user->pin_lock = '1';
    //      }

            if ($user->website_pin_selection == 'different_ip' || $user->website_pin_selection == 'different_country') {
                $user->pin_lock = '1';
            }
        }

    //  }

        // once again, i prefer boolean tests without the == for readability
        // if ($user->is_locked == '0' && $user->pin_lock == '0' && $user->website_pin_selection == 'every_login') {
        if (!$user->is_locked && !$user->pin_lock && $user->website_pin_selection == 'every_login') {
            $user->pin_lock = '1';
        }

        // not 100% sure on your logic here
        // why are we updating these fields if we detect a different ip or country, shouldn't we keep the original country and ip
        $user->ip_last = $request->ip();
        $user->last_country = $country;
        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('frontend.user.home');
    //      }
    //  }
    }
```